# In Sharepoint 2013 App getting error while running bellow mentioned code

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

Want to insert item in list.

Created a List in share point app 
After running the code in app , getting error .

Error - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    AddListItem("Company 1", "IT");


    function AddListItem(Company, industryVal) {

        $.ajax
            ({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CompanyInfo')/items",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify
                    ({
                        __metadata:
                        {
                            type: "SP.Data.ListItem"
                        },
                        Company: Company,
                        Industry: industryVal
                    }),
                headers:
                {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "POST"
                },
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    $("#ResultDiv").empty().text(data.d);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: try changing the __metadata to this: type: "SP.Data.CompanyInfoListItem"

Answer (score 0):

The string you are passing to `type` in `metadata` property is called as `ListItemEntityTypeFullName`. This property is very important while creating or updating items in SharePoint list.

You can get this property by using following REST endpoint:
 `siteUrl/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('DisplayNameOfList')/ListItemEntityTypeFullName`

**Reference**:

[SP.List.listItemEntityTypeFullName property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246655(v%3Doffice.15))